# Laravel relationship "fallback"

Tags: laravel

```
class Price extends Model {
    public function priceable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Venue extends Model {
    public function events() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
    }
    public function price() {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Price', 'priceable');
    }
}

class Event extends Model {
    public function venue() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Venue');
    }
    public function price() {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Price', 'priceable');
    }
}
```

What is the best way to have a fallback, if the event doesn't have a price assigned, to get it to use the event's venue price?
Is there a logical way to make this as a relation or should I just do everything in the Controllers?

Comment: I don't think you can do that in the relationship function, as that is also used for SETTING the price.  I would basically just create another method `getEventPriceAttribute()` for instance, which would basically `return $this->price ?= $this->venue->price;` which you can then easily use in your controllers by calling `$event->event_price;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a default model with optional custom values directly from the relation. This default model can be populated either from an array or an anonymous function:

```php
public function price()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Price', 'priceable')->withDefault([...]);
}
```

You can refer to [Laravel's documentation about default models](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#default-models) for some more explanation.

Comment: I think that's what I'm looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Event extends Model {
...
    public function getEventPriceAttribute() {
        return $this->price > 0 ? $this->price : $this->venue()->price
    }
...
}
```

By doing this, you can call Event object and get the price like this:

```
$eventObject->eventPrice;
```